# Why does ps o/p list the grep process after the pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, ps

When I do

```
$ ps -ef | grep cron
```

I get

```
root      1036     1  0 Jul28 ?        00:00:00 cron
abc    21025 14334  0 19:15 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

My question is why do I see the second line. From my understanding, `ps` lists the processes and pipes the list to `grep`. `grep` hasn't even started running while `ps` is listing processes, then how come `grep` process is listed in the o/p ?

Related second question:

When I do

```
$ ps -ef | grep [c]ron
```

I get only

```
root      1036     1  0 Jul28 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

What is the difference between first and second `grep` executions?

Comment: You'd be surprised of the outcome of `sleep 3 | sleep 3 | sleep 3` ;-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you execute the command:

```
ps -ef | grep cron
```

the shell you are using

(...I assume bash in your case, due to the color attribute of grep I think you are running a gnu system like a linux distribution, but it's the same on other unix/shell as well...)

will execute the `pipe()` call to create a FIFO, then it will `fork()` (make a running copy of itself). This will create a new child process. This new generated child process will `close()` its standard output file descriptor (fd 1) and attach the fd 1 to the write side of the pipe created by the father process (the shell where you executed the command). This is possible because the `fork()` syscall will maintain, for each, a valid open file descriptor (the pipe fd in this case). After doing so it will `exec()` the first (in your case) `ps` command found in your `PATH` environment variable. With the `exec()` call the process will become the command you executed.

So, you now have the shell process with a child that is, in your case, the `ps` command with `-ef` attributes.

At this point, the parent (the shell) `fork()`s again. This newly generated child process `close()`s its standard input file descriptor (fd 0) and attaches the fd 0 to the read side of the pipe created by the father process (the shell where you executed the command).

After doing so it will `exec()` the first (in your case) `grep` command found in your PATH environment variable.

Now you have the shell process with two children (that are siblings) where the first one is the `ps` command with `-ef` attributes and the second one is the `grep` command with the `cron` attribute. The read side of the pipe is attached to the `STDIN` of the `grep` command and the write side is attached to the `STDOUT` of the `ps` command: the standard output of the `ps` command is attached to the standard input of the `grep` command.

Since `ps` is written to send on the standard output info on each running process, while grep is written to get on its standard input something that has to match a given pattern, you'll have the answer to your first question:

1. the shell runs: `ps -ef;`
2. the shell runs: `grep cron;`
3. `ps` sends data (that even contains the string "grep cron") to `grep`
4. `grep` matches its search pattern from the `STDIN` and it matches the string "grep cron" because of the "cron" attribute you passed in to `grep`: you are instructing `grep` to match the "cron" string and it does because "grep cron" is a string returned by `ps` at the time `grep` has started its execution.

When you execute:

```
ps -ef | grep '[c]ron'
```

the attribute passed instructs `grep` to match something containing "c" followed by "ron". Like the first example, but in this case it will break the match string returned by `ps` because:

1. the shell runs: `ps -ef;`
2. the shell runs: `grep [c]ron;`
3. `ps` sends data (that even contains the string `grep [c]ron`) to `grep`
4. `grep` does not match its search pattern from the stdin because a string containing "c" followed by "ron" it's not found, but it has found a string containing "c" followed by "]ron"

GNU `grep` does not have any string matching limit, and on some platforms (I think Solaris, HPUX, aix) the limit of the string is given by the "$COLUMN" variable or by the terminal's screen width.

Hopefully this long response clarifies the shell pipe process a bit.

TIP:

```
ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating upon @Ben Jackson's answer.

Comment: I think running this will be a good illustration to this wonderful answer: `$ ps aux | grep grep | grep grep | grep grep | grep grep`  . You will see four lines of grep grep – all the ones in the pipe You created.

Answer (score 9):

The shell constructs your pipeline with a series of `fork()`, `pipe()` and `exec()` calls.  Depending on the shell any part of it may be constructed first.  So `grep` may already be running before `ps` even starts.  Or, even if `ps` starts first it will be writing into a 4k kernel pipe buffer and will eventually block (while printing a line of process output) until `grep` starts up and begins consuming the data in the pipe.  In the latter case if `ps` is able to start and finish before `grep` even starts you may not see the `grep cron` in the output.  You may have noticed this non-determinism at play already.

Comment: If ps blocks then the listing won't contain grep..correct. But Ignacio seems to suggest that grep has to be running. I am little confused.

Comment: I have actually not seen the non-determinism you mention! But it is quite interesting to note that.

Answer (score 8):

In your command

```
ps -ef | grep 'cron'
```

Linux is executing the "grep" command before the ps -ef command. Linux then maps the standard output (STDOUT) of "ps -ef" to the standard input (STDIN) of the grep command.

It does not execute the ps command, store the result in memory, and them pass it to grep. Think about that, why would it? Imagine if you were piping a hundred gigabytes of data?

**Edit In regards to your second question:**

In grep (and most regular expression engines), you can specify brackets to let it know that you'll accept ANY character in the brackets. So writing [c] means it will accept any charcter, but only c is specified. Similarly, you could do any other combination of characters.

```
ps aux | grep cron
root      1079  0.0  0.0  18976  1032 ?        Ss   Mar08   0:00 cron
root     23744  0.0  0.0  14564   900 pts/0    S+   21:13   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

^ That matches itself, because your own command contains "cron"

```
ps aux | grep [c]ron
root      1079  0.0  0.0  18976  1032 ?        Ss   Mar08   0:00 cron
```

That matches cron, because cron contains a c, and then "ron". It does not match your request though, because your request is [c]ron

You can put whatever you want in the brackets, as long as it contains the c:

```
ps aux | grep [cbcdefadq]ron
root      1079  0.0  0.0  18976  1032 ?        Ss   Mar08   0:00 cron
```

If you remove the C, it won't match though, because "cron", starts with a c:

```
ps aux | grep [abedf]ron
```

^ Has no results

**Edit 2**

To reiterate the point, you can do all sorts of crazy stuff with grep. There's no significance in picking the first character to do this with.

```
ps aux | grep [c][ro][ro][n]
root      1079  0.0  0.0  18976  1032 ?        Ss   Mar08   0:00 cron
```

Comment: I just added one more part to the question. It occurred to me that it was hard to read the "bounty notes". Thanks.

Comment: Ben Jackson (below) seems to suggest that ps could be running before grep and writing data to a kernel pipe.

Comment: As far as I'm aware which one starts first is rather irrelevant. The operating system doesn't necessarily allocate any CPU time to either of them until the STDOUT of PS is mapped to the STDIN of GREP.

Comment: You  want quotes. `c[ro][ro][n]` will be changed to `cron` before `grep` starts if you run the command in `/bin` or any other directory with a file named `cron` (or `corn`, or any other match) present. By contrast, `'c[ro][ro][n]'` won't be expanded. And it gets even messier if you run your original unquoted command in a shell with `nullglob` or `failglob` options enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote: "From my understanding, ps lists the processes and pipes the list to grep. grep hasn't even started running while ps is listing processes".

Your understanding is incorrect.

That is not how a pipeline works.  The shell does **not** run the first command to completion, remember the output of the first command, and then *afterwards* run the next command using that data as input.  No.  Instead, *both* processes execute and their inputs/outputs are *connected*.  As Ben Jackson wrote, there is nothing to particularly guarantee that the processes run at the same time, if they are both very short-lived, and if the kernel can comfortably manage the small amount of data passing through the connection.  In that case, it really could happen the way you expect, only by chance.  But the conceptual model to keep in mind is that they run in parallel.

If you want official sources, how about the bash man page:

```
  A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by the character |.  The format for a pipeline is:

         [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ | command2 ... ]

  The  standard  output  of command is connected via a pipe to the standard input of command2.  This connection is
  performed before any redirections specified by the command (see REDIRECTION below).

  ...

  Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).
```

---

As for your second question (which is not really related at all, I am sorry to say), you are just describing a feature of how regular expressions work.  The regular expression `cron` matches the string `cron`.  The regular expression `[c]ron` does *not* match the string `[c]ron`.  Thus the first grep command will find itself in a process list, but the second one will not.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual question has been answered by others, but I'll offer a tip: If you would like to avoid seeing the `grep` process listed, you can do it this way:

```
$ ps -ef | grep [c]ron
```

Comment: Thanks but I had further doubts, on the answers below. Please see my comments.

Comment: Why does using grep [c]ron not list the grep process, whereas using grep cron always lists the grep process? What is the effect of the bracket expression. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @abc It works because the `grep` regular expression matches exactly `c` followed by `ron`, but the `ps` output will show literally `grep [c]ron` since that was the command entered. Therefore, `grep`'s expression doesn't match it and filters it out.

Comment: This needs more quoting; make it `grep '[c]ron'` or else it'll become `grep cron` if you run this in a directory that contains a file named `cron` (as the shell replaces anything that looks like a glob with a list of files it expands to... and that's if you're lucky and it's on default settings; with `nullglob` it'll just become `grep` with no arguments, with `failglob` it'll become an error).

Answer (score 0):

`pgrep` is sometimes better than `ps -ef | grep word` because it exclude the `grep`. Try

```
pgrep -f bash
pgrep -lf bash
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$ ps -ef | grep cron
```

Linux Shell always execute command from right to left. so, before ps -ef execution grep cron already executed that's why o/p show's the command itself.

```
$ ps -ef | grep [c]ron
```

But in this u specified grep ron followed by only c. so, o/p is without command line because in command there is [c]ron.