# Why does pipeline order matter?

Tags: bash, pipeline

I have two programs in bash:

```
{ { sleep 1s; kill 0; } | { while true; do echo "foo"; done; kill 0;} }
```

and

```
{ { while true; do echo "foo"; done; kill 0; } | { sleep 1s; kill 0; } }
```

(just changed order).

How is it possible that the first one writes a lot of "foo" in the output and the second one writes nothing?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting two processes by a pipe redirects the output from the first to the second. Thus, connecting a process which writes output to a process that does nothing that output means no output occurs.

By contrast, connecting a process which does nothing to a process that generates output, the latter will proceed to generate output as usual.

By the way, what's the purpose of the `kill 0` lines? I doubt very much that they serve a useful purpose here.

Answer (score 2):

The second one does output `foo`, you just don't see it because it is piped to your second command.

You can prove this by redirecting to a file:

```
$ { { while true; do echo "foo" >> /tmp/f; done; kill 0; } | { sleep 1s; kill 0; } }
$ wc -l /tmp/f
56209
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because in the second command you are piping the output of a `echo` as the input of `{ sleep 1s; kill 0; }`

[What is a simple explanation for how pipes work in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834131/1006989)