# Difference between | and > operators

Tags: linux, shell

What is difference between the **pipe(|)** and **output(>)** redirection operators? Where can I use them?
For eg:
I have normally used pipe(|) only with grep

```
find . | grep abc
```

and the only use for input-output redirection I've come across is to test my programs with different input-output
For eg:

```
abc.exe < in.txt > out.txt
```

Why can't I do something like:

```
xyz.exe | out.txt
```

Comment: `|` pipes output to another program while `>` redirects it to file. That's why if you write `xyz.exe | out.txt` you will get error because `out.txt` isn't an executable file.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes (`|`) are used to string together small (yet focused) programs together to perform complex tasks.  This is a core UNIX philosophy.

For example:

```
$ ps -ef | fgrep http
$ sort myfile | uniq
```

Redirection (`>` or `2>`) is simply used to redirect *standard out* (`stdout`) or *standard error* (`stderr`) to a file.

For example:

```
$ sort myfile | uniq > newfile
$ find / -name andy\* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: So is there a list of these "focused" programs?

Comment: @KartikAnand Sorry I missed your comment.  No I don't think there is a definitive list; you will probably get a good subset by looking at some UNIX command line guides however.