# Unix pipe into ls

Tags: linux, unix, pipe, ls

I thought I understood *nix pipes until now... I have an executable called `studio` which symlinks to my install of `Android Studio` and I had assumed I could get the linked-to location with

```
which studio | ls -l
```

But that doesn't work. What it gives me is equivalent to having just run `ls -l` in the current directory.

If I run `which studio`, I get `/home/me/bin/studio`. And if I run `ls -l /home/me/bin/studio` I get the expected output showing me the symlink location.

So why doesn't the piped version work? What haven't I grokked about pipes?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To do that you need `xargs`:

```
which studio | xargs ls -l
```

From `man xargs`:

> xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input

To fully understand how pipes work, you can read [What is a simple explanation for how pipes work in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834118/1983854):

> A Unix pipe connects the STDOUT (standard output) file descriptor of
>   the first process to the STDIN (standard input) of the second. What
>   happens then is that when the first process writes to its STDOUT, that
>   output can be immediately read (from STDIN) by the second process.

Comment: This does not seem to work when I try it with ls without arguments. So `which studio | xargs ls` just outputs the result of which for me. Why does it require arguments to work?

Comment: @bdbdbd probably because `ls $(which studio)` is exactly the same. `ls`-ing the output of `which` is not going to give you anything else than a route, which is what `ls` gives as well.

Answer (score 33):

`ls` does not read its arguments from standard input, but from the command line. To get the directory at the command line, you have to use command substitution:

```
ls -l "$( which studio )"
```

(The double quotes are needed if the path might contain whitespace.)

Comment: The answer involving `xargs` is cleaner, but this honors my shell's color coding, which is a nice boon!

Comment: @Dannid when I tried xargs  I got `Too many errors from stdin` , but this answer worked to me out the box .

Comment: How could I know if a command reads its arguments from stdin or command line please?

Comment: @Tengerye: Read its documentation.

Comment: @Tengerye `man command`, in the head of the description section. If nothing says "read standard input" then it probably can't.

Answer (score 4):

Since `ls -l` does not take any input, it does not do anything regarding the output of `which studio`. The important thing here is understanding the difference between standard input and arguments. The standard input is a special file that is read using the `scanf` procedure (by a program in C for example), and the arguments to a program are passed to the main procedure as the `argv` and `argc` parameters. `argv` is an array of null terminated arrays of char, and `argc` is the length of that array.