# Pipe printf to ls in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I'm learning about pipes in bash and I found this pithy description:

> A Unix pipe connects the STDOUT (standard output) file descriptor of
>   the first process to the STDIN (standard input) of the second. What
>   happens then is that when the first process writes to its STDOUT, that
>   output can be immediately read (from STDIN) by the second process.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18211000/3960852)

Given this understanding, let's connect the STDOUT of `printf` to the STDIN of `ls`. For simplicity, print the parent directory (`printf ..`).

```
~/Desktop/pipes$ mkdir sub
~/Desktop/pipes$ ls
sub
~/Desktop/pipes$ cd sub
(no files)
~/Desktop/pipes/sub$ printf .. | ls
(no files)
~/Desktop/pipes/sub$
```

I want to be doing: `ls ..` but it seems that all I'm getting is `ls`. Why is this so? How can I `ls` the parent directory using pipes? Am I misunderstanding pipes?

Comment: `ls` doesn't read from standard input.  So, `ls ..` is the way to get what you want here.   `man ls` is your friend.

Comment: So is this simply a property of `ls`? Is my understanding of pipes otherwise correct? Is `ls ..` not taking the `..` argument from STDIN?

Comment: You need to use `xargs` with `ls` @KennethWorden

Comment: Yes, that's a property of `ls`, it doesn't read arguments from stdin (and therefore a pipe won't have any effect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many programs don't read from `stdin`, not just `ls`.  It is also possible that a program might not write to `stdout` either.

Here is a little experiment that might clarify things.  Carry out these steps:

```
cat > file1
This is file1
^D
```

The ^D is you pressing `<CTRL>+D`, which is the default end-of-file.  So, first we are calling the `cat` program and redirecting its `stdout` to `file1`.  If you don't supply an input filename then it reads from `stdin`, so we type "This is file1".

Now do similar:

```
cat > file2
This is file2
^D
```

Now if you:

```
cat < file1
```

You get:

```
This is file1
```

what if you:

```
cat file1 | cat file2
```

or:

```
cat file2 < file1
```

Why?  Because if you supply an input filename then the `cat` program does not read `stdin`, just like `ls`.

Now, how about:

```
cat - file1 < file2
```

By convention the `-` means a standard stream, `stdin` when reading or `stdout` when writing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `ls` does not read from `stdin` as you intended it to do. You need to use a tool that reads from the `stdin` like `xargs` and feed the read input to `ls`

```
printf "someSampleFolderOrFile" | xargs ls
```

`xargs man` page,

> xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input

Comment: My question was more about how pipes work, but thanks for your answer nonetheless.