# How to sort and count occurrence of lines in linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

How I can count occurence results of list in linux?

```
a
b
b
c
c
d

Result: a = 1 , b = 2 , c=2 , d=1
```

Answer (score 13):

I solved this by [piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash) to this command

```
sort | uniq -c
```