# What does a | (pipe character) do in a shell (bash) command?

Tags: bash

I have to run this command to install NPM. What does it do? What is the | at the end?

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.23.2/install.sh | bash
```

Also, am I running UNIX-like commands in Bash? Why does this work? Is it that Bash is a UNIX-command compatible interface for the terminal?

Comment: `curl` retrieves the indicated file, which happens to be a shell script, and that is piped into `bash` which is the shell program that will execute it. If you do a Google search on "what is bash" you'll find may explanations. But, yes, `bash` is one of several different Unix shell implementations.

Comment: @Zloj In the general case, that's true.  In the specific case of a well-known publisher and a trusted relationship as well as some reasonable way to vet the code, it's not quite that bad (but still bad).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Bash (and most *nix shells), the `|` (pipe) metacharacter¹ causes the shell to take the output from one command and uses it as the input for the next command.

What you are doing here is using `curl` to retrieve the `install.sh` file and then output its contents into `bash`, which is a shell that will execute the contents of `install.sh`.

In short, you are downloading and running the `install.sh` script.

---

1. A shell metacharacter is a character/symbol with a special meaning to the shell and it causes termination of a word unless it is quoted. For example, `|`, `>`, `<`, etc are shell metacharacters.

Comment: What do you mean "input for the next command"? Does the "bash" command take input?

Comment: All *nix programs have three streams, the standard in, the standard out and standard error.

When you pipe you passing the input to the standard in which the program can then use, similar to a parameter.

an example would be ```cat file | grep keyword | less```
Which would print the contents of a file, then filter the contents of the file and then present the result in a screen.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash does a better job of explaining it.