# Bash: how do you echo "hey" and ", how are you?" with two separate echo commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I'm new to Bash and I'm trying to learn how to firstly execute two commands using the | symbol, and secondly how to join two commands into a compound command.

When writing two commands in one line the pipeline symbol | is meant to connect the output of the first command to the input of the second. So I don't quite understand how it fails to join "Hey" and ", how are you?".

```
    echo "hey" | echo ", how are you?"
```

When writing a compound command, commands should be between the opening and closing braces separated by a semicolon. In this case

```
    { echo "Hey"; echo ", how are you" }
```

, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

What could I be missing out here, for these two cases?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: You can't just chain arbitrary commands together with `|`; [piping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9834086/113632) is a tool specifically for sending the output of one program into the input of a second program. If the second program isn't designed to handle that input you're just writing gibberish.

Comment: dimo414 learn to control your temper

Answer (score 5):

Short version: use `printf` instead of `echo`.

---

`echo` does not read from its standard input, so the pipe is effectively the same as

```
echo "hey"; echo ", how are you?"
```

which are two separate commands, each of which prints an implicit newline after the last argument.

Your brace command fails because a semicolon or newline is required after the last command: `{ echo "Hey"; echo ", how are you"; }`.

The answer to your question, though, is that you need to suppress the newline that `echo` prints.

```
echo -n "hey"; echo ", how are you?"
```

This will work for `bash`, but not all shells, as the `-n` option is non-standard. `printf` is more reliable:

```
printf "hey"; printf ", how are you?\n"
```

Comment: One thing to mention with `printf`: it's more robust to write `printf '%s' "$text"` when there might be a `%` in the text (not the case in the mcve, but can be an issue in real code).