# What does '|' mean in file /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, sysctl

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P
```

What does '|' mean in file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a simple explanation for how pipes work in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash)

Comment: It means `(take the stdout from this process) | (and tie it to stdin of this one)`

Comment: @ben this isn’t a question about bash, it’s about a file format.  It happens to be that the format adopts a notation used also in bash, but that doesn’t make the question a dupe.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the linux kernel documentation [/usr/src/linux/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt).

> [/proc/sys/kernel/]core_pattern is used to specify a core dumpfile pattern name.
>
> - If the first character of the pattern is a '|', the kernel will treat the rest of the pattern as a command to run. The core dump will be written to the standard input of that program instead of to a file.