# Execute shell command in Jenkins does not recognize the pipe character

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, command-line, sh

In the Execute shell command option in Jenkins I am trying to execute
xcodebuild -scheme "My project" test | xcpretty --report junit --output report.xml

But when Jenkins executes it, it looks like it does not recognize the pipe character and it takes it as next line or something.

Things I have tried
- Putting the command in a .sh file 
- Escaping the pipe character
- Use Eval

None of them have worked

I do not want to use the Xcode plugin for the moment.

Any tips to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your command-line code.
(Please don't make the wrong spelling.)

EDIT:  If it is not the pipe, then it could be that you need to take the output of the first command and wrap it so it sends it all at once... I might be wording that wrong.

```
OUT="$(xcodebuild -scheme "My project" test)"
echo $OUT | xcpretty --report junit --output report.xml
```

Comment: Did not work, same thing, I also tried putting it in the .sh file I created.

Comment: Hmm, let me do a test on my local Jenkins.

Comment: I execute the following command in the "Execute shell" section of Jenkins.. `echo "hello" | grep "hello"`.  There were no problems at all.  Maybe the issue is not with pipes?

Comment: Maybe, still have not found the way to fix it.

Comment: it looks like the problem was xcpretty, adding export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 worked, found the solution in https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty/issues/48. Thanks Jose for diagnostic

Comment: In my test, adding `#!/bin/bash` works, **BUT need to pay attention**, say we're running multi-line shell scripts with triple quotes, need to place the shebang at the right side of the `"""`, not at the next line of the `"""`.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like it's treating it as a newline because both commands are actually being executed at the same time; they are *not* executed sequentially. See [What is a simple explanation for how pipes work in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash)