# executables in pipes - are executables called once or repeatedly?

Tags: bash, pipe

If I have a long-running executable producing output - like `make` - piped into another executable, does the second executable get called once or repeatedly?

`make | my_exec`

I would accept a link explaining in depth how pipes work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a simple explanation for how pipes work in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash)

Comment: It gets called just once and keeps reading what it receives down the pipe till the input stops.

Answer (score 1):

The second executable is called once. It keeps reading the input until the first executable stops.

pipes basically just connect the STDOUt of one process to the STDIN of the next process.