# Parse input from stdin shell command

Tags: c, unix, redirect

How would one read the following in C?

```
./a.out < /bin/ls
```

I would like to read the output of `/bin/ls` command in my program. But first I need to figure out how to get that output. 
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the piping feature, that:

> [connects the STDOUT (standard output) file descriptor of the first process to the STDIN (standard input) of the second.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834118/13187605)

Example:

```
/bin/ls | ./a.out
```