# What does | command do in terminal?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pipe, io-redirection

I know for example: `ls -all | grep Hello` means to search all files containing `Hello`. What is the definitive definition of the `|` command? What exactly is going on here with `|`?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834118/9583293

Comment: Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

pipe; send whatever we get from the left side to the right side: (https://www.makeuseof.com/what-are-linux-metacharacters/) I would also take a look at the gnu bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html and check specifically the 3.2.3 Pipelines for more in depth information