# What does "ls | ./a.out" do?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I can't figure out what this command means:
`ls | ./a.out`

What is the "|" symbol for, and what does ls do when a file is used as a parameter instead of a directory?

Comment: Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash) if you want the nittry-gritty behind the scenes.

Comment: Have a look at the [POSIX shell docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02). BTW, the last sentence of your question does not make sense. Your `ls` does not get any parameter - neither file nor directory.