Spring boot application console logs to elastic search
I have one spring boot application which is generating logs in JSON format in console. And I want that logstash directly read that logs from console and provide to ELK.
Spring boot application logback.xml is as below:
<appender name="DATA-FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%message%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

and it's generating logs as below:
 {"@timestamp":"2024-06-20T09:34:36.632Z","Level":"DEBUG","Logger":"core","Thread":"main","classname":"com.app.AuditLoggerUtil","appName":"Core"}
{"@timestamp":"2024-06-20T09:34:36.648Z","Level":"DEBUG","Logger":"core","Thread":"main","classname":"com.app.AuditLoggerUtil","appName":"Core"}

I also started Elasticsearch and Logstash using below configuration:
input {
  stdin {
    codec => "json"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]  # Update with your Elasticsearch host
    index => "logs"          # Replace with your desired index name
  }
}

But when I am making http://localhost:9200/_sql to Elasticsearch with "query": "select * from logs" it givens me rows[] so somehow it's capturing logs.
Could someone please help me what I am missing and why it's not reading logs from console?
(Note: I don't want to use Kibana)

How do you start your application? What version of elasticsearch are you using? Is security enabled on elasticsearch side?

I start my application directly from IntelliJ as my testing it. Elastic Search version is 8.14.1. No security is enable in elastic search as of now so I can directly make request.

Based on your comment it doesn't look like your logstash instance is connected to your app in any way.
Each application has its own independent stdout and stdin streams. So, when you write into stdout in your application (that's what your logging is currently doing) you simply print things on the screen. And when you read from stdin in logstash it simply waits until somebody types something on its screen. These are totally independent streams. It is possible to redirect stdout of one application to stdin of another by for starting two application on bash command line at the same time and connecting them with the pipe | operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979785/783043 for more information.
Alternatively, you can change the configuration of your application, log into a file and make logstash read from the file instead of stdin.
