# Detect non-empty STDIN in Clojure

Tags: clojure, stdin

How do you detect non-empty standard input (`*in*`) without reading from it in a non-blocking way in Clojure?

At first, I thought calling using the [`java.io.Reader#ready()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready()) method would do, but `(.ready *in*)` returns `false` even when standard input is provided.

Comment: How would you do it in Java? Then, you could just use Java interop.

Comment: I've also looked for Java solutions, but alas, have found none.

Comment: What is the use-case for this?  The simplest answer is to use a separate thread and just do blocking reads.

Comment: The use case is to detect if the program was provided with some data on standard input. If that is the case, then the program reads the provided data, otherwise moves on.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for? [InputStream .available](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available())

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (if (> (.available System/in) 0)
    (println "STDIN: " (slurp *in*))
    (println "No Input")))
```

---

```
$ echo "hello" | lein run
STDIN:  hello

$ lein run
No Input
```

---

**Update**: It does seem that `.available` is a race condition checking STDIN. n alternative is to have a fixed timeout for STDIN to become available otherwise assume no data is coming from STDIN

Here is an example of using core.async to attempt to read the first byte from STDIN and append it to the rest of the STDIN or timeout.

```
(ns stdin.core
  (:require
   [clojure.core.async :as async :refer [go >! timeout chan alt!!]])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [c (chan)]
    (go (>! c (.read *in*)))
    (if-let [ch (alt!! (timeout 500) nil
                       c ([ch] (if-not (< ch 0) ch)))]
      (do
        (.unread *in* ch)
        (println (slurp *in*)))

      (println "No STDIN"))))
```

Comment: I tried this before and it seemed not to work. Your example works just like I wanted. I'll investigate it a bit more.

Comment: Great, I see what your intent is now. I am going to delete my other answer.

Comment: `.available` seems to be non-deterministic. Running `lein run | lein run` can either output "STDIN:  No Input" or "No Input".  The same happens for `.ready`. Do you know what's happening here?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible. See this answer for a good description of a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384207/3438870

Comment: to expand, I do see the same behavior as you. My guess is that there is a race condition between the OS adding data to stdin and the application checking. I did some more tests and if I check a few times with 10 ms sleep between checks there are cases where there is no data in stdin and then it changes to being available.  That goes back to your original problem of it isn't really deterministic.  You could block for a set amount of time and if nothing shows up on stdin assume nothing ever will and move on.

Comment: Reading the Go solution, I wonder if detecting non-empty STDIN would be feasible if wrapped in a clojure.async channel.

Comment: Thats actually what I have been playing around with using a combination of `alts!!` `timeout` channel and a `go` block that is blocking.  It isn't ideal because you are essentially putting a sleep in your application if no input is supplied

Comment: Can you re-wrap the byte stream into a `Reader`? A minor point: one final closing parenthesis is missing.

Comment: I think there are a lot of different ways you could do this.  A bit more condensed solution is do call `.unread` and put the byte read back on the stream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html#unread(int) you can then just call `slurp *in*`  I updated the example with that strategy

Comment: By calling `.unread` yes but it appears the way unread works is you have to supply what to _unread_. `reset` always throws an exception from the java docs "The reset method of PushbackReader always throws an exception." You cannot simply reset the stream after it is read.

Comment: I'm still getting non-deterministic results for `lein run | lein run`. I only changed printing STDIN to `(println (str "STDIN: " (slurp *in*)))`, so that I can distinguish when is STDIN found to be non-empty. I run `lein run | lein run` several times and both `No STDIN` and `STDIN: No STDIN`.

Comment: That is more of a question of how does `|` work.  Both processes of `lein run` are running in parallel with the left side of `|` sending STDOUT to STDIN of the right side.  Both have a fixed timeout to wait for input, with the processes executing in parallel it is a race condition to which one will finish first.   An example of the problem is if you run `(sleep 5 && echo "hi") | lein run` This will always show "No STDIN" because echo is called after the wait for STDIN has finished.  But if you run `(sleep .1 && echo "hi") | lein run` You should always get the STDIN.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash#comment31919026_9834118 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9694841/3438870 for descriptions of the behavior you are seeing.  So I believe that this is a partial answer to your question about detecting stdin but it does cause issues if you are chaining this strategy together.

Comment: I ran `(sleep 5 && echo "hi") | lein run` several times and I always got "STDIN: hi". I'd expect that any sleep longer than the timeout of 500 ms will cause STDIN not to be detected, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: There is overhead from `lein run` as well `time lein run
No STDIN
lein run  5.59s user 0.35s system 107% cpu 5.508 total` (on my machine) I think you might want to refine or ask a new questions at this point.  This may not be the solution you are looking for, for your use case. I think this should work fine if the start of the pipe is a producer of data like `cat` `echo` `printf`

Comment: In my case the initial producer is the same script, typically invoked via its uberjar or by `lein run`. At the end, I decided to ask the user to provide an explicit command-line flag that an input is piped, instead of trying to detect it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PushbackReader?  You can use it like:

1. Read a byte (blocking). Returns char read or -1 if stream is closed.
2. When returns, you know a byte is ready.
3. If the byte is something you're not ready for, put it back
4. If stream is closed (-1 return val), exit.
5. Repeat.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/PushbackReader.html

If you need it to be non-blocking stick it into a `future`, a `core.async` channel, or similar.

Comment: I tried that but found that you cannot unread a byte from STDIN. Moreover, this blocks until provided with input, so it would need to be combined with a timeout.